# No Task in ThreadPoolExecutor , will the ThreadPoolexecutor die?

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have created the static object for ThreadPoolExecutor class and in my web application I'm adding tasks to ThreadPoolExecutor for every request.

My question is after all the requests are processed and what happen to ThreadPoolExecutor class(in my case I have created the static object for thread poolexecutor) whether It becomes shut down the service or still waiting for new tasks to submit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't shut it down with [`executor.shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdown()) it'll stay running of course, waiting for tasks that may never come.

I'm sure this is described in the Javadocs for the class, but for some reason reading the Javadocs seems to be uncool these days.

Comment: Sorry @Kayaman.. I have seen below in "A pool that is no longer referenced in a program AND has no remaining threads will be shutdown automatically" in the finalization section of the doc.. and confused

Comment: Why confused? As long as you do not set that static reference to your Executor to null, it will be referenced and thus kept alive. I do not know how you would make it more clear in the docs?

Comment: @prababuddy That just means there's a safety mechanism (like many of JDK classes). Depending on the way you get your hands on an executor, it may be closed by the container, framework or whatever. In most cases however you'll need to make sure you handle the shutting down yourself.